# Can you deploy a SharePoint ACE as a web part on a page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-aces

I have build the ACE and deployed to App catalog but unfortunately I cannot add as web part.

I am able to add it to the dashboard but I was wondering inf you're able to just add it like a web part to a SharePoint page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a wrapper web part, the [react-adaptivecards](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-adaptivecards) sample webpart is an example of this.

Comment: Even tough this works for adaptive cards that are just json based. I am trying to use the new Adaptive cards extention that are generated by the yo-man generator. These create an sppkg, and in the workbench you are able to add it like a webpart. So i was wondering after deployment you would be able to do the same